# Using Kronecker delta to evaluate $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos n x \cdot \cos x d x$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a proof in which I have to evaluate this:
$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos{nx}\cos{x}  dx,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So far I have used trig. identities and brute force (pages lon calculation) to calculate this. Wonder if there is neat why using that fact that for all integers $k$ I have
$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i k x} d x=\delta_{k, 0}$.

Comment: Euler's formula comes to mind.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? If you mean $(e^x+e^{-x})/2$, I have tried that. This still gives long calculations.

Comment: There's an $i$ missing in the exponents. Yes, I meant that. Amounts to $\cos (nx)\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\cos \bigl((n+1)x\bigr) + \cos \bigl((n-1)x\bigr)\bigr)$ at the end, which arguably is quicker to obtain via trigonometric identities. The Euler-formula approach has the advantage that one needn't recall the trig identities, however.

Comment: Also, tried that. Buy one still has to du multiple integrals, substitution etc. But maybe this can not me avoided.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{a-\pi}^{a+\pi} \cos (kx)\,dx = \delta_{0,k}$$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is rather easy to see.

Comment: First use $\cos (n x) \cos x=\frac{1}{2}(\cos ((n+1) x)+\cos ((n-1) x))$ and then $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{a-\pi}^{a+\pi} \cos (k x) d x=\delta_{0, k}$, right?

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos^2(x) dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (cos(2x)+1) dx= \pi$.

For $n\neq 1$ we have using the identity $cos(nx)cos(mx)=\frac{cos((n+m)x)+cos((n-m)x)}{2}$ we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos(nx)cos(x) dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos((n+1)x)+cos((n-1)x) dx=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{sin(x(n+1))}{n+1}+\frac{sin(x(n-1))}{n-1}]|^{x=\pi}_{x=-\pi}=0$.

Thus $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} cos(nx)cos(x) dx=\pi \delta_{n, 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As Daniel fisher commented , use identity:

$Cos(nx) Cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}[Cos(n-1)x+Cos(n+1)x$

For $$\int Cos(mx)dx$$ see my answer in this site.

Comment: I do not think that this is correct:
$\int \cos (m x) d x$

Comment: which site are u talking about?

Comment: I said this site that means Math. Stacck Exchange. I do not know how to use citation to refer to that  question. but you can find it  in my answers (in user sirous).

Answer (score 0):

The integral $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\cos(nx)\cos(mx)\mathrm{d}x}$$
For some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Is $1$ if $m=n$ and is $0$ otherwise. These functions are known as [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_functions). Use this fact to solve your problem.